# cdecl and stdcall calling conventions in Native Nuget

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to build a native nuget package that offers a pivot on calling conventions, providing DLLs with both cdecl and stdcall conventions for x86 builds.  (Most users prefer cdecl calling conventions, but .NET users who P/Invoke this library would prefer stdcall for various reasons.)

My `.autopkg` contains both cdecl and stdcall pivots:

```
nuget
{
    [nuspec omitted for brevity]

    files {
            [Win32,cdecl] {
                lib: build\x86-cdecl\Debug\git2-0_21_0.lib;
                bin: build\x86-cdecl\Debug\git2-0_21_0.dll;
                symbols: build\x86-cdecl\Debug\git2-0_21_0.pdb;
            }

            [Win32,stdcall] {
                lib: build\x86-stdcall\Debug\git2-0_21_0.lib;
                bin: build\x86-stdcall\Debug\git2-0_21_0.dll;
                symbols: build\x86-stdcall\Debug\git2-0_21_0.pdb;
            }
    };
}
```

Building the `.nupkg` using the native nuget scripts appears to succeed and installing and using the nuget package within a standard C project (one with cdecl calling conventions) succeeds.

However, if I create a new C project and set the calling conventions to stdcall and install the nuget package, I do not get the stdcall version of my library.  Instead, the cdecl version is installed and I cannot link.

I was optimistic that the nuget package manager would detect my project's configuration and use the appropriate calling convention pivot (like it does for the processor type), but that does not appear to happen.  Nor am I given an option to select a calling convention manually.  Yet the fact that there *is* a pivot in the autopkg configuration makes me think that I *could* select one.

How can I take advantage of this pivot?

Comment: Hmm. That *should* have worked.

Quick Question: which version of the tools and VC++ are you using? 

    PS > show-coapptoolsversion

I may need to see the generated package files.

Comment: @GarrettSerack - VS 2013 Update 2 and CoApp Powershell Developer Tools Version 1.23.521.0.  The `.autopkg` and resultant `.nupkg`s are at http://www.edwardthomson.com/temp/libgit2.0.0.3.0.zip

Comment: @GarrettSerack Is there something I need to do differently in my VS project's setup to flag it with its calling conventions?  Or does nuget read my compiler flags to determine this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, this is completely impossible.  It is, sadly, equally impossible to get help.

Native Nuget is, regrettably, a barely tested, almost inoperable and completely unsupported wasteland of missed opportunity.  The only answer it to simply not use it.